# ¿ Como esperar 2 veces por la carga completa de un documento?

Tags: javascript, webix

Tengo un documento, cuya carga se realiza **en 2 veces**:

1. Cargo los archivos `.js` necesarios.
2. Desde uno de esos archivos, establezco el `href` de la hoja de estilos a utilizar.
3. **Cuando se termine la carga de la hoja de estilos** es cuando quiero *pintar* en la pantalla.

El objetivo es evitar el *feo* efecto de *aplicar* los estilos **después** de mostrar la página; se aprecia claramente el cambio diseño.

Actualmente, lo hago así:

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<link id="SKIN.CSS" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="lib/spin.min.js"></script>
<script id="APP.JS" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="FSAUX" style="height:1em;width:1em;left:100%;position:fixed;top:100%;"></div>
<div id="CMAUX" style="height:1cm;width:1cm;left:100%;position:fixed;top:100%;"></div>
<script>
window.Gui = { };

window.App = {
  $Spinner: new Spinner( )
};

App.$Spinner.spin( document.body );

( function( ) {
  var curr = window.location.href,
      url = 'app.php?sw=' + screen.width.toString( ) + '&sh=' + screen.height.toString( ),
      element = document.getElementById( 'FSAUX' );

    curr = curr.substring( 0, ( curr.indexOf( '#' ) == -1 ) ? curr.length : curr.indexOf( '#' ) );
    //this removes the query after the file name, if there is one
    curr = curr.substring( 0, ( curr.indexOf( '?' ) == -1 ) ? curr.length : curr.indexOf( '?' ) );
    //this removes everything before the last slash in the path
    curr = curr.substring( curr.lastIndexOf( '/' ) + 1, curr.length );

    url += '&fw=' + element.offsetWidth.toString( );
    url += '&fh=' + element.offsetHeight.toString( );

    element = document.getElementById( 'CMAUX' );
    url += '&cw=' + Math.round( screen.width / element.offsetWidth ).toString( );
    url += '&ch=' + Math.round( screen.height / element.offsetHeight ).toString( );

    url += '&file=' + curr;

    document.getElementById( 'APP.JS' ).src = url;
} )( );
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="lib/webix_debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="lib/i18n/es.js"></script>
<script>
webix.ready( function( ) {
  webix.i18n.setLocale( 'es-ES' );
  webix.ui.fullScreen( );

  App.Load( );
} );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Desde ahí, llamo a la *verdadera* aplicación, generada en `PHP`. El código que realmente *llega* al navegador es

```
App.Load = function( ) {
  document.getElementById( 'SKIN.CSS' ).href = 'http://cdn.webix.com/4.3/webix.css';
  webix.ready( App.Run );
}

App.Run = function( ) {
  'use strict';

  App.$Routes = {
    'home': App.Home
  }

  window.onbeforeunload = onUnload;

  // Prevenimos el botón 'back'.
  if( ( 'history' in window ) && ( 'pushState' in window.history ) ) {
    onNavigateBack( );
    window.addEventListener( 'popstate', onNavigateBack );
  }

  Gui.Init( );

  // ... Resto del código ...
```

Como se ve, hay **2 llamadas** a `webix.ready( )`. Una en el `index.html`, desde donde llamo a `App.Load( )` al terminar de cargar las dependencias del primero.

Una vez en `App.Load( )`, establezco el `href`, y **vuelvo a llamar a** a `webix.ready( )`, para lanzar la **verdadera** función de inicio: `App.Run( )`. Este esquema **no funciona**. `App.Run( )` se llama **antes** de cargar los estilos.

También he probado una versión *pedreste* de lo anterior:

```
App.Load = function( ) {
  document.getElementById( 'SKIN.CSS' ).href = 'http://cdn.webix.com/4.3/webix.css';

  setTimeout( loaded, 0 );

  function loaded( ) {    
    if( document.readyState === 'complete' ) {
      setTimeout( App.Run, 0 );
    } else
      setTimeout( loaded, 10 );
  }
}

App.Run = function( ) {
  'use strict';

  App.$Routes = {
    'home': App.Home
  }

  window.onbeforeunload = onUnload;

  // Prevenimos el botón 'back'.
  if( ( 'history' in window ) && ( 'pushState' in window.history ) ) {
    onNavigateBack( );
    window.addEventListener( 'popstate', onNavigateBack );
  }

  Gui.Init( );

  // ... Resto del código ...
```

Aparentemente, `webix.ready( )` solo se puede llamar 1 vez por documento. En la versión *pedreste*, parece que el estado de `document.readyState` **no cambia** después de finalizar la carga completa la primera vez.

¿ Como espero a que el documento se cargue por completo **2 veces** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si el objetivo es saber cuando se carga el CSS para ejecutar los códigos de inicio, podrías sustituir el `<script>` de tu index.html con este codigo:

```js
window.onload = function(){
  // Cuando carge tu pagina
  webix.i18n.setLocale( 'es-ES' );
  webix.ui.fullScreen( );  
  
  // Se añade el elemento CSS
  var hojaCss = document.createElement('link')
  hojaCss.rel = 'stylesheet'
  hojaCss.type = 'text/css'
  hojaCss.link = 'http://cdn.webix.com/4.3/webix.css'
  document.getElementsByTagName('head').appendChild(hojaCss)
  
  // Cuando carge el css
  hojaCss.onload = function(){
   App.Run()
  }
}
```

Asi se establece lo que necesitas:

1. Que cargue primero el HTML, JS.
2. Despues de la carga que se añada el css y se cargue.
3. Cuando este el CSS cargado, ejecutar `App.Run()`